# Does this sequence converge pointwise and/or in $L^1$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $a_n(t)=\frac{1}{n} \text{1}_{ [0,n)}(t)$. Does this sequence converge in $L^1/$pointwise?

My ideas: We have for all $t$: $\mathbf{1}(t)\in\{0,1\}$ and
$$0 \leq \frac{1}{n}\textbf{1}(t) \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq \left| \frac{1}{n}\textbf{1}(t)\right|^p \leq 1 \quad \forall p\ge1$$

So it's a null sequence and we have dominated convergence with dominated function $g(t)=1$. $g(t)=1$ is integrable so all $a_n$ is integrable for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point-wise it clearly converges to zero.

In the $L^1-$norm, it DOES NOT converge, since
$$
\|a_{2n}-a_n\|_{L^1}=1
$$
and hence it is not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: The $L^1$ norm equals $\frac12$